# Resetting I2c Address - MLX90614

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, i2c

I was using my MLX90614 IRTherm sensor flawless and bought two more. I have connected two sensors serial with pull-ups to `SDA --> A4 and SCL --> A5`. After digging the internet I found out that I should change their default slave addresses to different addresses so that Arduino can recognize their 7-bit slave addresses. 
After changing their address, now I can't read either two new serial MLX'es or my old MLX.

- I might have messed up with their addresses and don't know how to
  reset their addresses.
- How can i connect multiple sensors/ how can i change their adress properly?

> reading sensor data

```
#include <Wire.h> // I2C library, required for MLX90614
#include <SparkFunMLX90614.h> // SparkFunMLX90614 Arduino library

IRTherm therm; // Create an IRTherm object to interact with throughout

const byte LED_PIN = 8; // Optional LED attached to pin 8 (active low)

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize Serial to log output
  therm.begin(0x5A); // Initialize thermal IR sensor
  therm.setUnit(TEMP_F); // Set the library's units to Farenheit
  // Alternatively, TEMP_F can be replaced with TEMP_C for Celsius or
  // TEMP_K for Kelvin.

  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT); // LED pin as output
  setLED(LOW); // LED OFF
}

void loop() 
{
  setLED(HIGH); //LED on

  // Call therm.read() to read object and ambient temperatures from the sensor.
  if (therm.read()) // On success, read() will return 1, on fail 0.
  {
    // Use the object() and ambient() functions to grab the object and ambient
    // temperatures.
    // They'll be floats, calculated out to the unit you set with setUnit().
    Serial.print("Object: " + String(therm.object(), 2));
    Serial.write('°'); // Degree Symbol
    Serial.println("F");
    Serial.print("Ambient: " + String(therm.ambient(), 2));
    Serial.write('°'); // Degree Symbol
    Serial.println("F");
    Serial.println();
  }
  setLED(LOW);
  delay(500);
}

void setLED(bool on)
{
  if (on)
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  else
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
}
```

> Setting address
>
> ```
> #include <Wire.h> // I2C library, required for MLX90614
> #include <SparkFunMLX90614.h> // SparkFunMLX90614 Arduino library
>
> IRTherm therm; // Create an IRTherm object to interact with throughout
>
> const byte oldAddress = 0x5A;
> const byte newAddress = 0x5B;
>
> void setup() 
> {
>   Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize Serial to log output
>   Serial.println("Press a key to begin");
>   while (!Serial.available()) ;
>
>   therm.begin(oldAddress); // Try using the old address first
>
>   byte address;
>   if (!therm.readID()) // Try reading the ID registers
>   {
>     // If the read fails, try re-initializing with the
>     // new address. Maybe we've already set it.
>     therm.begin(newAddress);
>
>     if (therm.readID()) // Read from the ID registers
>     { // If the read succeeded, print the ID:
>       Serial.println("Communicated with new address.");
>       Serial.println("ID: 0x" + 
>                      String(therm.getIDH(), HEX) +
>                      String(therm.getIDL(), HEX));
>     }
>     else
>     {
>       Serial.println("Failed to communicate with either address.");      
>     }
>   }
>   else
>   {
>     // If the read suceeds, change the address to something
>     // new.
>     if (!therm.setAddress(newAddress))
>     {
>       Serial.println("Failed to set new address.");
>     }
>     else
>     {
>       Serial.println("Set the address to 0x" + String(newAddress, HEX));
>       Serial.println("Cycle power to try it out.");
>     }
>   }
> }
>
> void loop() 
> {
>
> }
> ```

Edit 1:
[Datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Temperature/MLX90614_rev001.pdf)

Comment: what does the datasheet say about resetting the address?

Comment: I couldnt find anything about it

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 13 of 35 in the datasheet states:

> In order to provide access to any device or to assign an address to a
>   SD before it is connected to the bus system, the communication must
>   start with zero SA followed by low RWB bit. When this command is sent
>   from the MD, the MLX90614 will always respond and will ignore the
>   internal chip code information.

Supposedly, all you have to do is to connect only one device and use the address zero to read/write the registers.

Comment: I didn't understand  "low RWB bit" part

Comment: that is the read/write bit ... see figure 4 ..... the library should take care of it

Comment: I am doint what it says but not sure if zero SA = default adress

Comment: Maybe the problem is I2C speed. MLX90614 supports only 100KHz i2c. If your i2c is at 400KHz, there would be no response from MLX90614.